# Minimum velocity for a pendulum to rotate a quadrant

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, work, home-experiment

> Suppose a pendulum is allowed to rotate in a vertical plane(z-x) shown below:
>
> [image]
>
> What is the minimum velocity that it must start with such that it rotates an angle of $ \frac{\pi}{2}$ degrees?

In the proof where we find out minimum velocity such that it completes a rotation, we say that at the topmost point the centripetal force cancels the gravity force and hence tension is zero. Using this we find the horizontal velocity and plug it into the energy conservation equation.

However, if we try to do a similar procedure for when it is made to complete one quadrant, we can't use a similar proof because when the pendulum is at a horizontal position then the centripetal force and gravity force is perpendicular, so you can't really equate them.

---

**Relevant equations:**

In the horizontal direction, the force is given as:

$$ T = m \frac{v^2}{r}$$

In vertical direction, the force is given as:

$$ ma_y = -mg$$

Seems like I can't say that the tension is zero because it'd lead to $ v= 0 $ when the object may have a vertical velocity at that point.

---

Note: I know that at a horizontal position, the velocity must be purely vertical  from the constraint equation.

$$ x v_x + y v_y = 0$$

Comment: For calculating the minimum to complete one quadrant, you can take its velocity at the horizontal position to be 0

Comment: When the pendulum is horizontal $y=0$ so $v_x=0$ i.e. the velocity is *vertical* not horizontal (of course, $v_y$ could also be zero).

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Are we to assume you haven't learned conservation of energy or are just trying to do this without it?

Comment: How did you conclude that I haven't learned the conservation of energy? I had explicitly stated energy conservation in my post. Edit: On second thought, sort of yes, I'm trying to reason it out using Newton's laws if that is what you are saying.

Comment: Why can't you use just use conservation of energy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the proof where we find out minimum velocity such that it completes a rotation, we say that at the topmost point the centripetal force cancels the gravity force and hence tension is zero. Using this we find the horizontal velocity and plug it into the energy conservation equation.

For this case, if the velocity at the topmost point $H$ is $0$ then the bob just falls down. Even if we give the bob some small horizontal velocity at the topmost point it follows a parabolic path and falls down (because the string is not taut). Still, if the velocity at the topmost point is $0$ then velocity at the lowermost point $L$ will be $\sqrt{4gr}$ (by energy conservation principle). That means if we were to give the bob a horizontal velocity of $\sqrt{4gr}$ at $L$ it would complete its circular motion up to the point some point $P$ between $A$ and $B$, at which tension in the string would be zero, and then fall following a parabolic trajectory.
That means there is some minimum horizontal velocity $v_0$ for which the tension of the string will not be zero, bob will not start falling and will continue with its circular motion around the circle. That velocity comes out to be $\sqrt{5gr}$.

However, when it is made to complete one quadrant there is no requirement to calculate a limiting velocity because there is nowhere to follow a parabolic path (there is nowhere to fall even if the tension in the string becomes zero). We can just use the energy conservation equation to calculate the velocity at whatever point we may require.
If you don't want to directly apply the equations of energy conservation you could proceed by finding out the equations of motion
$$\ddot{\theta}=-\frac{g}{r}\sin \theta$$
This innocent looking differential equation is actually quite nasty and does not have a solution using elementary functions. You could, however, proceed by using
$$\ddot{\theta}=\dot{\theta} \frac{d\dot\theta}{d\theta}$$
whose first integral will just give you back the energy conservation equation (or it might take you nowhere!).

Comment: ". That means there is some minimum horizontal velocity v0 for which the tension of the string will not be zero, bob will not start falling and will continue with its circular motion around the circle. That velocity comes out to be" Does this mean you sending $ T \to 0 $ in the proof which is shown for that formula?

Comment: Yes, for finding that limiting velocity we take the limiting  case of $T \rightarrow 0$ at the highest point.